# Leaflet Opacity Control Using Slider For Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, leaflet, html, bootstrap-framework, transparency-opacity

I am attempting to use the [Slider For Bootstrap](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-slider/) to update the opacity of a layer within Leaflet.

The slider also needs to be in a Bootstrap Popup but this part is working.

As per this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joshuadickerson92/uTwM8/105/) you can see I have the slider working but I cannot get it to update/ set the opacity of the background layer, how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a `setOpacity` method for [TileLayer](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer). This should do what you want:

```
$('#rangeSlider').slider().on('slide', function (ev) {
    sliderVal = ev.value;
    background.setOpacity(sliderVal/100);
});
```

**EDIT**: Here is an example fiddle with sliders for controlling opacity of both the background (with `.setOpacity`) and a vector layer (with `.setStyle`):

http://jsfiddle.net/nathansnider/zkcs36p6/

Comment: Would this also work for layers that aren't tiled, for example a leaflet JSON layer?

Comment: There is a `setStyle` method for [Path](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#path) elements, which is inherited by all vector layers. That should work for everything except regular Markers. It would go something like `myLayer.setStyle({fillOpacity : sliderVal/100});` (or `{opacity : sliderVal/100}`, for lines or outlines).

Comment: Is it possible to combine both fillOpacity and opacity into one so that the overall transparency of a polygon that has a line boundary would change at once?

Comment: Of course! Just set both options within the same `.on('slide', ...)` event handler, like `myLayer.setStyle({fillOpacity : sliderVal/100, opacity : sliderVal/100});`